# Swift ArraySlice index out of Range for Item[0] in Non-Empty Array in While loop

Tags: arrays, while-loop, swift2

This is related to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557914/arrayslice-index-out-of-range-in-swift), but the answer only showed how to make that instance work but didn't explain what was wrong so I'm not sure how to make mine work.
Below is the code in question:

```
let texts = ["abcdeb", "abbd", "abde", "abcd", "abcde"]
var start = 0
while start < texts.count {
    var newtexts = texts[start..<texts.count] + texts[0..<start]
    print("ding", newtexts)
    print("dong", newtexts[0])
    start += 1
}
```

It produces the following:

```
ding ["abcdeb", "abbd", "abde", "abcd", "abcde"]
dong abcdeb
ding ["abbd", "abde", "abcd", "abcde", "abcdeb"]
fatal error: ArraySlice index out of range
```

By changing the index I'm referencing to 1, I get the loop successful twice, but the result is "abbd" both times. 2 gets me three successful loops and "abde", and so on.

Any ideas what's happening and how I can fix it?

Thanks!

edit: I can get this to work if I switch to "newtexts[newtext.startIndex]" But I'm not sure why as I'm making a new array each time, shouldn't the startIndex always be 0?

Comment: Edited to show partial solution.

Comment: Ah, so you are trying to reverse the order of elements in the array?

Comment: No, not reverse. The first run through I want to preserve the order, the second run through I want to pop the first element and add it two the end. The third I want to remove the first two and put them at the end, etc. Order is maintained, just shifted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
let texts = ["abcdeb", "abbd", "abde", "abcd", "abcde"]

var start = 0

while start < texts.count {

 var newtexts = texts[start..<texts.count] + texts[0..<start]
 print("ding", newtexts)
 print("dong", newtexts[start]) // Or, you could use Array(newtexts)[0] instead of newtexts[start]
 start++
}
```

Apparently the first value of `newTexts` cannot be accessed by 0 every time you run the loop. **After** the loop is run once, `newtexts` no longer has an element that can be accessed by 0. The second time it is run, it no longer has an element that is accessed by 1, and so on. This is because of the way in which you defined `newtexts`.

If you create a new array, for example,

```
var arrayz = texts[1...3] + texts[3...4]
arrayz[0] // Error, Bad instruction...
```

You get an error over here because this new "array" consists of elements that can be accessed starting from `1`. This is similar to what happened in your earlier loop.
The "array" `newtexts` (or `arrayz`) that you are creating isn't actually an array; it is of type `ArraySlice<String>`. This means that it is not accessed how you would a normal array. You will be able to access its elements based on how you defined it.

Hope you understood. :)

Comment: Makes sense. I was under the delusion, I guess, that a part of an array plus a part of an array made a new array, not a new part of an array. I assume this is because of Swift's type inference safety protocols. Thanks for helping.